# What is the most lightweight method to load different image file formats in nodejs and read pixels?

Tags: node.js, image, file-format, image-loading

Is there a unified and lightweight method for loading multiple common image file formats in NodeJS which provides read access to individual pixels?

- It should support gif, jpeg, and png.
- Preferably it would either support other image formats too or provide a way to add more. (webp, etc.)
- It does not need to be able to save the file again after modifying pixels, provide metadata access, or anything else.
- It doesn't need to be able to load images from URLs.

So far the libraries that support multiple image formats are heavyweight, such as providing full canvas support or full image processing support.

Is there a lightweight way to do this that I'm not finding?

Comment: What things/libraries you tried so far that you found "heavyweight"? And what weight exactly is heavy for you, how would you define something as a lightweight? Any benchmarks you have in mind for this?

Comment: The first things I found were [node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) which is built off [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/), [opencv4nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs) which is a full image processing/computer vision package, [node-imagemagick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick) which "Requires imagemagick CLI tools to be installed", and [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp), which is a full image processing library, but probably a lot lighter than the others.

Comment: AN ADVICE: Never use image magic, search for `image tragic` in google and you see why. Probably they might have resolved it, but use it with extreme care.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why I couldn't find this one before posting here:

[get-pixels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-pixels)

Given a URL/path, grab all the pixels in an image and return the result as an ndarray. Written in 100% JavaScript, works both in browserify and in node.js and has no external native dependencies.

Currently the following file formats are supported:

- PNG
- JPEG
- GIF

It hasn't had any updates for two years but seems the most lightweight. I'm guessing people might mostly use [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) these days. It doesn't seem to have external dependencies and is actively developed, but includes a lot of image processing functionality I don't need.